# Confused on applications of solving $\cos \frac x2 - \sin x = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Why can't $\cos\frac{x}{2} - \sin x = 0 $ be transformed into being $\cos(x) - \sin(2x) = 0$? It works in application to achieve the half angle formulas for $\sin x$, $\cos x$, and $\tan x$, why doesn't it work here?

Comment: I meant  cos (x/2) - sin(x) = 0

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but we *can* write $u = \frac{x}{2}$ and rewrite the equation as $\cos u - \sin 2 u = 0$ and then apply the double-angle formula to the second term on the l.h.s.

Comment: Maybe the reason it doesn't work for you is that you failed to change the variable as Travis did, and therefore confused the value of $u$ for being the value of $x$ that you were after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (not-reasonable) confusion stems from the difference in how *identities* and *equations* use their variables.

- In an **identity** such as $\cos 2 x = 2\cos^2 x - 1$, the "$x$" stands for "*any* number". (That's the special nature of identities!) Thus, replacing "$x$" by, say, "$x/2$" wherever it appears "works" ---that is, yields a still-true statement--- because $x/2$ is *also* "any number".
- In an **equation** such as $\cos(x/2) - \sin x=0$, the "$x$" stands for "a *particular* number" ... or, more precisely, "a member of a *particular set* of numbers". Replacing "$x$" by "$2x$" wherever it appears **changes the meaning** of the symbol "$x$" to "a member of *some other* set of numbers". For instance, the original equation has $x=\pi$ as a solution. In the "$2x$" version, $\cos x - \sin 2x = 0$, the corresponding solution is $x=\pi/2$. The "$x$" is being used differently.

Now, in the second situation, if you keep careful track of things, solving the $2x$-equation and recalling that "these new $x$s are half(!) the size of the original $x$s, so we need to convert back, ...", then everything's fine. However, such an argument can be very hard to follow by your audience (or even yourself, if you get distracted in the middle of work). The better, *safer* strategy is to introduce an auxiliary variable, as in: "Let's define $y:=x/2$, so that we can write the equation as $\cos y - \sin 2y = 0$." Then, when you find that $y=\pi/2$ is a solution of the transformed equation, there's no confusion over which $x$ solves which equation; moreover, the conversion to a solution of the original equation is crystal clear to everyone: $x=2y=2(\pi/2) = \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*
Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$; $\cos (x/2) - \sin x = 0$ iff $\cos (x/2)[ 1 - 2\sin (x/2) ] = 0$; $\cos (x/2)[ 1 - 2\sin (x/2) ] = 0$ iff $\cos (x/2) = 0$ or $\sin (x/2) = 1/2$.

Comment: You beat me to it!  Well done.  +1

Answer (score 0):

$\cos x=2\cos^2\dfrac x2-1=2\sin^2x-1=-\cos2x$

So, we need $\sin2x=-\cos2x\iff\tan2x=-1$

$2x=n\pi-\dfrac\pi4\  \ \ \  (1)$ where $n$ is any integer

$\cos\dfrac x2=\sin x=\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2-x\right)$

$\implies\dfrac x2=2m\pi\pm\left(\dfrac\pi2-x\right)$ where $m$ is any integer

Check for both the signs if  they conform to $(1)$